# Microchip pic access registers by address

Tags: pic, microchip

Is it possible to access a PIC register by address?

Why I'd want to do that? because I need to compute it beforehand (for ports). If a function receives PORTX, it can figure out TRISX, LATX and ANSELX by adding an offset.

The include files use the `__at` macro to define registers

```
extern volatile PORTAbits_t PORTAbits __at(0x00C);
#define __at(x) __attribute__((address(x)))
```

I'm assuming `__attribute__` and `address` are compiler specific?

Can I use that with memory map to access the computed address?

Comment: Have a look: https://microchipdeveloper.com/faq:38

Comment: Thanks @Mike, that's for accessing RAM. What I need is to access PORTX, TRISX, ANSELX

Comment: If you mean to make it a one general library code for all PICs, then you can't. I son't know much about 16 and 32 bit PICs, but a wide range of 8 bit PICs uses banked RAM and the addressing of special function registers is different for different family groups. What you want to achive `If a function receives PORTX, it can figure out TRISX, LATX and ANSELX by adding an offset.` is not suitable for this type of memories. It can be implemented on linearly addressed memories. These special function registers are also located in RAM.

Comment: Have you ever read a PIC datasheet? Have you seen how the register memory is mapped?

Comment: thank you @Kozmotronik but I think I did

Comment: I'm glad to hear that @sh4rp3r. Can you use the same function or library without changing anything to compute address on other PIC models? Or it is just for your PIC model specific? As a matter of fact I'm a bit curious about how and what you did.

Comment: I'm working with a couple of 8-bi mid-range PICs so I thought to create a reusable function that takes an argument and figure related data direction and analog select registers. I have no intention to create a library that includes all PICs.
I tried `__at` macro but it didn't work. `asm{}` and looks like `#asm ... #endasm` not an option.

Comment: Do you implement something like modbus communication? What is the reason behind this access registers by address idea?

Comment: Afaik the PIC32MX peripheral libraries does use (volatile) pointers to SFRs. For 16-bit dspic it is also possible see https://www.microchip.com/forums/m794597.aspx by yours truly

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working (at least for what I want to achieve) by using pointers and offsets.

As an example PIC12F1571, has:

- `PORTA` @ `0x00C`
- `TRISA` @ `0x08C`
- `ANSELA` @ `0x18C`

To set the port to digital output:

```
    volatile unsigned char *direction = &PORTA + 0x080;
    volatile unsigned char *mode = &PORTA + 0x180;
    
    *mode = 0;
    *direction = 0;
```